# Cannot read property 'push' of undefined?

Tags: angular

I have the following simple code:

```
  export class Years {

      private years: number[];
      private currentYear: number;

      constructor() {
        this.currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
        this.years.push(this.currentYear + 1);
        for (let i = this.currentYear; i < this.currentYear - 5; i--) {
          this.years.push(i);
        }
      }
}
```

It gives me an error: `Cannot read property 'push' of undefined?`? Why if I have correct data type as array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to initialize years to empty array, otherwise it is null

```
 private years: number[] = [];
```

Comment: Could have been a comment. If Anyone with less reputation had given the same answer, "superior" users would have started complaining :)  Just adding my thought here since I have seen this happen :)

Comment: yes it could have been, but there are cases in which you need to post an answer so that it will be useful for the future users. i have seen this too , but at this moment i cant find the duplicate question

Comment: ...could also have been mark as a dupe. A simple google search would give an answer.

Comment: yeah marked it already

Comment: @sajeetharan, people post here to get a solution to their problems, i dont mind if its a comment or an answer, i am not againt that, as long as the problem is solved for the OP. Its just the dual standards i am talking about :)

Comment: @Faisal, I don't have a dual standard at least. Doesn't matter who is, I'm equally mean to all people, haha. These types of questions should not be answered at all in my opinion, when there are so many dupes out there for example on this and would think a high-rep user would know that, so in that sense I'm more forgiving to low-rep users actually.

Comment: @AJT_82 your "equally mean" comment made my day, cheers ;)